# IllegalArgumentException deploying CAS 5.3.10 Maven Overlay WAR on Wildfly 14

Tags: maven, wildfly, war, web-deployment, cas

I'm deploying CAS 5.3.10 on Wildfly 14, using a Maven Overlay as specified in https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuring-Servlet-Container.html#external and using the project template at: https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/tree/5.3

I have already edit the pom which deploys correctly on Wildfly 9, but on Wildfly 14  deploy fails with the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an
>   instance of declaring class   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils.invokeVfsMethod(VfsUtils.java:100)
>     at org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils.getFile(VfsUtils.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.VfsResource.getFile(VfsResource.java:90)
>     at org.apereo.cas.util.CasVersion.getDateTime(CasVersion.java:59)   at
>   org.apereo.cas.util.SystemUtils.getSystemInfo(SystemUtils.java:50)
>   ...........

The problem seems to be related to the `CasVersion` class that attempts to access via VFS (via spring) to retrieve information related  last modification date of the module.

Comment: I had the same issue. I did not find a solution so I downgraded to wildlfy 12.

Comment: @leopal i successfully deploy War on wildfly 14
I verified that VfsUtils class of Spring is used only in the CasVersion class.
At this point, being in overlay, I created the org.apereo.cas.util.CasVersion class in my project, avoiding the use of the VfsResource in the getDateTime method

Comment: Nice, feel free to answer your question to help others who will face the same issue.

Comment: @Marco I couldn't get you. could you please explain in detail. I'm actually stuck with this

Comment: @leopal have you resolved this issue

Comment: @RaviMCA Have you tried Marco's solution mentioned on comment above?  I haven't tested myself but I guess it will work.

Comment: @leopal I couldn't understand his solution. I tried to create the class but got the compilation errors and couldn't build the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since @Marco didn't provide his fix, I will. For anyone having the same issue follow below steps to resolve:

1. After checking out `cas-overlay-template`, create `CasVersion.java`
   under `src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/util` with the following content:

```
package org.apereo.cas.util;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.core.io.VfsResource;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;


/**
 1. Class that exposes the CAS version. Fetches the "Implementation-Version"
 2. manifest attribute from the jar file.
 3.  4. @author Dmitriy Kopylenko
 4. @since 3.0.0
 */
@Slf4j
@UtilityClass
public class CasVersion {

    /**
     * @return Return the full CAS version string.
     * @see java.lang.Package#getImplementationVersion
     */
    public static String getVersion() {
        return CasVersion.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    }

    /**
     * Gets specification version from the manifest package.
     *
     * @return the specification version
     */
    public static String getSpecificationVersion() {
        return CasVersion.class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion();
    }

    /**
     * Gets last modified date/time for the module.
     *
     * @return the date/time
     */
    @SneakyThrows
    public static ZonedDateTime getDateTime() {
        final Class clazz = CasVersion.class;
        final URL resource = clazz.getResource(clazz.getSimpleName() + ".class");
        if ("file".equals(resource.getProtocol())) {
            return DateTimeUtils.zonedDateTimeOf(new File(resource.toURI()).lastModified());
        }
        if ("jar".equals(resource.getProtocol())) {
            final String path = resource.getPath();
            final File file = new File(path.substring(5, path.indexOf('!')));
            return DateTimeUtils.zonedDateTimeOf(file.lastModified());
        }
        // These lines are causing the reported exception so we just comment them out.
        // if ("vfs".equals(resource.getProtocol())) {
        //     final File file = new VfsResource(resource.openConnection().getContent()).getFile();
        //     return DateTimeUtils.zonedDateTimeOf(file.lastModified());
        // }
        LOGGER.warn("Unhandled url protocol: [{}] resource: [{}]", resource.getProtocol(), resource);
        return ZonedDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

5. Add below dependencies to `pom.xml`

```
    <!-- Required for lombok imports -->              
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>  
    <!-- Required for DateTimeUtils to be available on classpath -->              
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-core-util</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

3. Replace any occurrences of `<app-server>-tomcat</app-server>` with `<app-server></app-server>` since you gonna provide application server.

Above steps should be enough to resolve **the reported issue**.

Answer (score 0):

as leopal says,It's work.
I compiled the Java file above and replaced it with a JAR package
I tried to replace the `cas-server-core-util-api-5.3.16.jar` version of the JAR package.

Comment: Hello. This is technically not an answer to the proposed question. Please either upvote the answer that worked for you, and/or leave a comment on that answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).